# Laravel, Auth::user() in controller

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel framework- Why aren't I able to use Auth::user(), (to see if user has been logged in) in the controller of the laravel project. Is the Session not connected to the controller?

HomeController.php

```
 public function isauthorized(){
    if (Auth::user()){
        return View::make('home.basic')
            ->with('basic1', 'Authorized');
    }else{
        return View::make('home.basic')
            ->with('basic1', 'Not Authorized');
    }
}
```

My login system is working and the session is always set when logged in. When I call the function Auth::user() in the View or in routes.php, it is succesfull. But when I call the function in the controller, it is false. Help please.

Comment: Simple debugging. Use `dd(Auth::user());` before your `if`.

Comment: Make sure that the app/storage directory is writable by the Web Server

Answer (score 22):

The problem is that you haven't included the Auth facade.

In your HomeController.php do:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

Comment: `auth()->user()` without any `use`

Answer (score 8):

Just add the following in your controller library.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

Comment: This is the same solution provided by [Zaerdna' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35010871/908174) earlier this year. When you answer a question, be sure you add value on top of the existing answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

If you're on Laravel 5.x, you'll probably have the auth middleware component. That might be the missing link.

I often use a pattern like this in my controllers:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->user =  \Auth::user();
    }
```

then you can

`if ($this->user .. )`

or

`if ($this->user->can('something'))`   [with Entrust or similar](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust#checking-for-roles--permissions)

Answer (score 5):

To see if a user is loged in don't use `Auth::user()`. Use `Auth::check()` instead.

```
if (Auth::check()){
    return View::make('home.basic')->with('user', Auth::user());
}
```

Comment: Why would `Auth::check()` be better? I quote: _In other words, Auth::check() calls Auth::user(), gets the result from it, and then checks to see if the user exists. The main difference is that it checks if the user is null for you so that you get a boolean value._  stackoverflow.com/a/33483798/460885

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the Auth facade in the controller;

add this line just before class definition.

```
use Auth;
```

Answer (score 3):

in your controllers constructor:

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. The solution I've found, is to not use \Auth::user() (it returns null). Instead, go through the guard like this: `\Auth::guard('mrm')->User()`. Obviously replace 'mrm' with whatever auth guard you are using.

This works, correctly returning the current user even when Auth::User returns null, and you can also use other methods on it - e.g. `\Auth::guard('mrm')->check()` instead of `\Auth::check()` (which always returns false).

No idea why the Auth facade doesn't work, but at least there is an alternative that does.

Answer (score 1):

additionally, you can also use the `auth()` helper without adding the facade in your controller. (i.e. `auth()->user()`

Answer (score 0):

Use `Auth::check()`function to check if user is logged or not

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('web');
    }

    public function isAuthorized()
    {
        if (Auth::user()) {
            return view('home.basic')->with('basic1', 'Authorized');
        } else {
            return view('home.basic')->with('basic1', 'Not Authorized');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add an explanation to this answer to make it useful and so it is up to standard. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer