# Laravel 5.5, Auth::user() not working in Controller.php

Tags: php, laravel

I follow the video [Multiple Authentication in Laravel 5.4 Natively! (Admins + Users) - Part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iKRLrJXNN4M)
From part1 to 5, it's all done. Now I can login, logout.
Buy when I want to get the admin's properties, I got problem.

In admin blade, I can use {{ Auth::user()->name }}, it's ok.
In Composer, it's also ok.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\ViewComposers;
use Illuminate\View\View;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;

class AdminComposer
{
  /**
   * Create a movie composer.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function __construct(Request $request)
  {
    $this->admin= Auth::user();
    $this->base = config('app.url') . '/admin/';

  }

  /**
   * Bind data to the view.
   *
   * @param  View  $view
   * @return void
   */
  public function compose(View $view)
  {
    $view->with('admin', $this->admin);
    $view->with('base', $this->base);
  }
}
```

Then I try to use View in Controller, there is nothing, and no error message.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Auth;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
  use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

  public function __construct()
  {
    $admin = Auth::user();
    echo "<pre>", print_r($admin, 1), "</pre>"; exit;
    if(!empty($admin)){
      View::share('admin', $admin);
    }
  }
}
```

Why Auth::user() is ok in blades and composer, not working in controller ?

---

**/config/auth.php**

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
],
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],

    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Admin::class,
    ],
],
```

---

Maybe I found the reason. Though still not resolved.

In laravel's Controller.php, it's not working.
But in any other controller I created, it's ok

For example, the following is ok.
**App\Http\Controllers\Admin\HomeController.php**

```
public function __construct()
{
  $this->middleware('auth:admin');
  parent::__construct();
}

public function index()
{
  $admin = Auth::user();
  dd(Auth::user());
}
```

Maybe this is because the middleware.

In other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25027996/laravel-authuser-in-controller), someone uses Auth::guard('mrm')->User()
But I do the same, I tried Auth::guard('admin')->User()
Still nothing...

Comment: What happens when you dd(Auth::user())?

Comment: What the error ?

Comment: are u missing $this->$admin = Auth::user(); in controller

Comment: try the auth()->user() from the global helper

Comment: dd(Auth::user()) and dd(auth()->user()) are both null

Comment: Possible duplicate of [laravel 5.4 : cant access Auth::user() in the \_\_construct method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45055618/laravel-5-4-cant-access-authuser-in-the-construct-method)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Laravel 5.3 you are no longer able to access session in controller constructors, [because middleware has not run yet](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-53-session-in-constructor). Authenticating a user, or getting the authenticated user requires session middleware to have already run.

[You can define a closure](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0) (scroll to "Session In The Constructor") that happens after the session middleware has run.

Answer (score 1):

I typically use `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth` as the pulled in namespace. Try that.